# How to renew a value when a value is larger than it, counting the time of the record being broken at the same time

Tags: replacement, counting

I have a given value and is it possible that after some calculation, when the calculated result is larger than the given value, the given value can be set as the value that is larger than it? Other than that, I also need to count the time of the value being replaced. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am marking this question as a duplicate since you have asked a very similar question before. However, below is what you need to implement. The counter will count the number of times the value is changed.

```
counter = 0;
If[newvalue>oldvalue, oldvalue = newvalue; counter+=1]
```